# DelimitMate.vim -- how can I expand return inside triple quotes?

Tags: python, vim

When writing python doc string, one often has to do this:

```
"""
this is a docstring
"""
```

and in vim, with DelimitMate.vim, I'd do this:

1. type `"""|` and then get `"""|"""`
2. press `<CR>` and get this:

   ```
   """
   |"""
   ```

which is not quite satisfying, because I have to type `<CR>` again when I'm done with the string, is there any way that I can type `<CR>` in `"""|"""` and get this:

```
"""
|
"""
```

Comment: Didn't you find anything interesting in `:help delimitmate`?

Comment: @romainl I've `let delimitMate_expand_cr=2` and <CR> expanding works inside brackets, but not triple quotes.

Comment: Then the feature is not implemented. I suggest sending a feature request via the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read the docs carefully, there's this option:

```
au FileType python let b:delimitMate_expand_inside_quotes = 1
```

that does exactly what I wanted.
And this is my [vimrc](https://github.com/timfeirg/workspace-setup/blob/master/.vimrc) if the above line didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should test it yourself with something like:

```
:inoremap <expr> <cr> getline('.')[col('.')-4:col('.')+1]=='""""""' ? "<cr><esc><up>o" : "<cr>"
```

Notes:

- I haven't checked whether it'll get the indentation right in Python
- If this is only for python, add `<buffer>` to the mapping, and define it in a python ftplugin
- This mapping doesn't check context or anything else.